# Set textbox value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

How can I set the value of a textBox value using Javascript?

I can read the value of the `txtUserName` field in my AJAX method. But in the two commented rows give an error:

```
  function handle_geolocation_query(position) {

       // $("input#MainContent_txtEnlem").val() = position.coords.latitude;
       // $("input#MainContent_txtBoylam").val() = position.coords.longitude;
        PageMethods.SendLocation($("input#MainContent_txtUserName").val(), position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }
```

I'm using jQuery 1.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in you code is that you are assigning the value to function. What you should do is pass the value as agrument, so your code will be:

```
$("#MainContent_txtEnlem").val( position.coords.latitude);
$("#MainContent_txtBoylam").val(position.coords.longitude);
```

Some other points:

- If you are making use of `id` then there is no need to write `input#...`.
- This is a jQuery function. It's not pure JavaScript.

Comment: Just to elaborate: `val()` returns the value. So you're trying to assigning the new value to the `string` that was returned, not to any property of the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use $("#textboxId").val("some text");  What error does it give when you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it gives you an error because you're trying to assign a value to a function.